# Java EJB @Asynchronous loop - How to know when all the calls are complete before moving on?

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, glassfish, ejb

I have this code in an ejb

```
for (PayrollEntry pe : payroll.getEntries()) {
    recalculatePayrollEntry(pe);
}

CalculateTotals(payroll);
```

which calls this async method

```
@Asynchronous
public void recalculatePayrollEntry(PayrollEntry pe) {
    // Calculate Payroll Entry;
    pe.setEarningsEntries(newEarnings);
}
```

What is the best way to wait until all those recalculations execute before calling CalcuateTotals?

Comment: Just a comment, if you wait for all jobs to complete, you may not gain any advantage of asychronous processing... especially if you have a synchronization point (like a certain row in database) all jobs must synchronize on.

Comment: Each of those calculations takes a while, and they are only using one core. Since none of them rely on each other, I want to be able to use multiple cores to process them at the same time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of having your async method as `void`, return a [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) (which represent an asynchronous calculation). Start up the jobs, collect all the futures, and then await their completion:

```
Future<?> recalculatePayrollEntry(PayrollEntry pe) {
    // Calculate Payroll Entry;
    pe.setEarningsEntries(newEarnings);
    return new AsyncResult<Object>(null); // just something symbolic
}

// Usage:
List<Future<?>> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (PayrollEntry pe : payroll.getEntries()) {
    results.add(recalculatePayrollEntry(pe));
}
for (Future<?> result : results){
    result.get(); // await completion
}

CalculateTotals(payroll);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can have your method return an [`AsyncResult`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/AsyncResult.html) which is a `Future`. The return type of the method should be `Future`

Collect all futures in a list, and then call `.get()` on each.